# Internal Server Error when trying to create Meeting in MS Graph

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, httprequest

I'm trying to create an application that creates a Meeting. I used the code from the  [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http), but when I tried to execute it in the Microsoft Graph Explorer, I get this:
[image: MS Graph Error]

Are there currently some errors when trying to create a meeting, or is there something I'm doing wrong? I gave the needed permission, and I even tried it with the beta version too, but same result.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error here is mainly due to the request body having an invalid format of the DateTime properties.

Please specify the startDateTime and endDateTime as below.

```
{
  "startDateTime":"2021-01-07T14:30:00.0000000-07:00",
  "endDateTime":"2021-01-07T15:30:00.0000000-07:00",
  "subject":"Test Graph"
}
```

It worked for me as you can see the below image.

[image]